# How populate a select tag in HTML to JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Qfj/) which works fine in HTML as you can see, but how get the values of the `<select />` tag to insert in my bean ?

Something like this:

```
<h:outputLabel for="state" value="State:" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{bean.state}" />
```

I'm trying a lot of things but nothing so far.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to work. JSF needs to know about all of the dropdown items.

*Either* use a plain HTML `<select>` element instead of `<h:selectOneMenu>` and grab the submitted value by `@ManagedProperty` or `<f:viewParam>`, *or* port that JS code to JSF backing bean code so that you can use `<f:selectItems>`. You can use `<f:ajax>` to fill and render the 2nd dropdown.

Comment: I choose to set these values in a backing bean as you suggest.

Comment: Just one question @BalusC, what you use use to populate a country, state, city field automatically ?

Comment: Just JSF with `<f:ajax>` and the data in application scope.

Comment: I mean some API that provide this kind of service.

Comment: To get the data from, you mean? So far we've always maintained the countries/states (but not cities) ourselves. I haven't had a project yet which also requires a dropdown of cities (would be too much work to collect and maintain yourself). As to 3rd party APIs, I've only ever heard of Yahoo PlaceFinder. Note that your JavaScript code has all those states/cities hardcoded in the `.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript functions seem to take the `id`s of the `select`s.

If you do `<h:form prependId="false">` and `<h:selectOneMenu id="city"` then "city" will be the `id` of the `select` rendered by JSF. Just pass that `id`s to the functions.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{bean.selectedCity}">

    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{bean.selectedState}">

    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        new dgCidadesEstados({
            cidade: document.getElementById('city'),
            estado: document.getElementById('state')
        });
    });            
</script>
```

Comment: Won't work. You'll ultimately end up with `Validation error: Value not valid` when the form is submitted, because the list of items is not known by JSF.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes Balusc, it populates the values but ends up with the error you mentioned on submission. +1 for the your solution and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<h:selectItems>` tag. A nice introduction is [here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/15-introduction-to-jsf-core-tags-library-5.html) and [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) .

Comment: but how do I populate them through the javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I have an **stupid** (or **funny**) idea when i integrate [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) into JSF (take a look, it is wonderful).

Thus, CKEditor does not support JSF fully, but it supports HTML and JS (jQuery) themselves. When editing in CKEditor, it create other tags for user to input on it, and when user submit information to server, nothing found in that. So I created a `<h:inputTextArea value="#{bean.textEditor}"/>` and when user submit, it run a script to set its value to that `<h:inputTextArea/>`  :)

***Back to your question***, i would fire a JS script to do that trick :).You can use `<h:inputHidden value=#{bean.city}/>` and `onclick` event on submit button or something like that to do that trick :). But in this case, you have to validate data yourself to make sure that this information is vaild.